# Are these answers useful?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, answer-quality

I realize [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound) is a really old question which may require moderator's attention.

I suggest we lock it or close it as new answers show up which in my opinion seem a bit useless. I am specifically talking about the *Mine was caused by this and that*.

How is that even an **answer**? It doesn't attempt to answer the original question but it may somehow be useful to future visitors.

Are any actions required in terms of moderation?

Comment: The new answer that was just posted is definitely not an answer, deleted. The rest of the answers and the question all seem fine.

Comment: I voted to close with the Off topic: no valid code to reproduce the error close reason. It's a vague question attracting bad answers. (It's not quite equivalent to "I keep getting syntax errors. What is syntax and how can I stop getting errors", but... it's close.)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn how does *`I had this issue and it turned out to be an incorrect table alias. Correcting this resolved the issue.`* answer the 5 questions raised by the OP? Also, I disagree this question is on topic according to today's rules

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Check out [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521731/1438393) too, while you're at it.

Comment: @AmalMurali: it's an attempt to answer the question and isn't worthy of a VLQ flag.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy It's not quite "not an answer", but it might classify as very low quality - at least give an example or something, and how to fix it.